# Why the MSE of the fitted data is not equal to the sum of the bias and the variance in R?

Tags: r, regression, variance, bias, mse

I use simple linear regression and I want to find the decomposition of MSE, that is as a sum of the bias, the variance and the variance of the error terms. I have the following code:

```
n <- 100
Sigma <- 2
x <- rnorm(n, 0, 3)
y <- x + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(Sigma))

sim_data <- data.frame(y,x)

model <- lm(y ~ x, data = sim_data)
mse1 <- mean(summary(model)$residuals^2)

fitted <- predict(model,data.frame(x))
mse2 <- mean((fitted-y)^2)

# decomposition of MSE into bias, variance and variance of error
mse3 <- mean((x-mean(fitted))^2) + var(fitted) + Sigma
```

`mse1` and `mse2` are equal, but `mse3` is not the correct MSE. What am I doing wrong in the decomposition of MSE into bias, variance and variance of the error terms?

Comment: Do you think `mse2` and `mse3` are calculating the same thing?

Comment: @AlexJ this is what I am trying to do. I want to make the decomposition of `mse2`, but what I am doing in `ms3` seems to be wrong. So, how can I write `mse2` as a sum of bias, variance and variance of errors?